# I want to continuously move an Icon up and down using AnimatedAlign, but I can't make it work

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, riverpod

I created an animation to move an Icon up and down using Riverpod. It was working fine until yesterday, but when I checked today, it's not working (it doesn't move). I haven't made any particular changes, so I don't know why it's not working anymore. Can you provide any hints on what might be wrong?

```dart
class UpDownHandDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const UpDownHandDialog({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 90,
      width: 90,
      child: Consumer(
        builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, _) {
          final upDownHandNotifier = ref.read(upDownHandProvider.notifier);
          final isTopAlignment = ref.watch(upDownHandProvider).isTopAlignment;
          return AnimatedAlign(
            alignment:
                isTopAlignment ? Alignment.topCenter : Alignment.bottomCenter,
            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            onEnd: () => isTopAlignment
                ? upDownHandNotifier.downHandIcon()
                : upDownHandNotifier.upHandIcon(),
            child: const Icon(
              CupertinoIcons.hand_point_left_fill,
              size: 40,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
part 'up_down_hand_notifier.freezed.dart';

final upDownHandProvider =
    NotifierProvider.autoDispose<UpDownHandNotifier, UpDownHandState>(
  UpDownHandNotifier.new,
);

class UpDownHandNotifier extends AutoDisposeNotifier<UpDownHandState> {
  @override
  UpDownHandState build() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => downHandIcon());
    return const UpDownHandState(isTopAlignment: true, isDisplaying: true);
  }

  Future<void> upHandIcon() async {
    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 400));
    state = state.copyWith(isTopAlignment: true);
  }

  Future<void> downHandIcon() async {
    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 400));
    state = state.copyWith(isTopAlignment: false);
  }

  void hideUpDownHandDialog() {
    state = state.copyWith(isDisplaying: false);
  }

  Future<void> showUpDownHandDialog() async {
    state = state.copyWith(isDisplaying: true);
  }
}

@freezed
class UpDownHandState with _$UpDownHandState {
  const factory UpDownHandState({
    required bool isDisplaying,
    required bool isTopAlignment,
  }) = _UpDownHandState;
  const UpDownHandState._();
}
```

When I debugged using breakpoints, it seems that the onEnd of AnimatedAlign is being executed, but the alignment is not. Therefore, the Icon is not moving as expected.

```dart
alignment: isTopAlignment ? 
              Alignment.topCenter : Alignment.bottomCenter,
```

Even though this part is not executed,

```dart
            onEnd: () => isTopAlignment
                ? upDownHandNotifier.downHandIcon()
                : upDownHandNotifier.upHandIcon(),
```

This part is being executed... I wonder why...